# Skip numpy __new__ in ndarray subclass (or possibly overriding/defining classes in C or cython)

Tags: python, class, numpy, subclass, cython

Ultimate goal: have `isinstance(MyClass(), np.ndarray)` and `issubclass(MyClass, np.ndarray)` both return `True` *without* `MyClass` calling `np.ndarray.__new__()`.

---

Let's say I've implemented all the methods of `numpy.ndarray` and I want to set it up so that it will pass `isinstance` checks for `ndarray`, but I *don't* want it to actually call `__new__` from `ndarray`.

Initially, I was thinking of something like this:

```
import numpy as np
class BlockingClass(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

Unfortunately, trying to instantiate `Dummy()` yields this error about it not being safe:

```
TypeError: object.__new__(Dummy) is not safe, use numpy.ndarray.__new__()
```

This works if it's a class that subclasses object:

```
class BlockingClass2(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls)

BlockingClass2() # No error
```

I'm pretty sure that it's because `ndarray` is a C class, so I was thinking of overriding it in a c-class (or, preferably, a Cython class) and using multiple inheritance to get the typecheck to work without calling `__new__`.  So my class would be:

class MyClass(BlockingClass, np.ndarray):
    pass

where `BlockingClass` would be the c-defined function. I'd really prefer to do this in Cython instead, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.  I've tried doing:

```
cdef class BlockingClass:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

but this generates the same 'unsafe' error as well as with `__cinit__`.

```
cdef class BlockingClass:
    def __cinit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
        return self
```

But, when `BlockingClass` is subclassed with multiple inheritance like above with an object that defines `__new__`, that `__new__` method is still called.  If I can't do this in Cython, what's the minimal amount of C code I would need to define a baseclass that, through multiple inheritance, would skip `ndarray`'s `__new__`?  Maybe I can cimport a function to instantiate the class without going up the mro?

Comment: I'm still very unclear about why you think you need to do this ... If it has all of the methods of an ndarray, why do you need to check the type?  And your code where you're trying to return a different type from `__new__` certainly won't behave like an ndarray no matter what you try to do since `__init__` will never be called.

Comment: @mgilson backwards compatibility. The class previously subclassed ndarray, now it doesn't need to, client code might still check for the object by checking if it's a subclass of ndarray. It's just weird because you can override `__init__` and not pass it up super, but there's no way to override `__new__` without passing it up the mro...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is possible to fake `isinstance` and `issubclass`, but in the following approach you can define your class passing to `np.ndarray.__new__` only the arguments that you want:

```
import numpy as np
class BlockingClass(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ndarray_kw = ['shape', 'dtype',  'buffer' 'offset', 'strides', 'order']
        to_ndarray = {}
        to_myclass = {}
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            if k not in ndarray_kw:
                to_myclass[k] = v
            else:
                to_ndarray[k] = v
        new = np.ndarray.__new__(cls, *args, **to_ndarray)
        for k,v in to_myclass.items():
            setattr(new, k, v)
        return new

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.test = 1
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly fake the `isinstance` in Python, but you certainly cannot create a class that would work the same for the native code in numpy without calling its `__new__`.

I was thinking of everything complicated but, then realized that some functions you are calling might also return `ndarray`; if you want them completely replaced then you can monkeypatch the numpy module to have your class instead, this might be the only way; or replace ndarray with a module with a class with metaclass that has a subclass hook that will say that the original ndarray and your class are both instances of the same...

Or if only the isinstance is troubling, then do something really really dirty, and try

```
import __builtin__

_original_isinstance = __builtin__.isinstance
class FakeArray(object):
    pass

def isinstance(object, class_or_type):
    if _original_isinstance(object, tuple):
        if ndarray in class_or_type:
            class_or_type += (FakeArray,)

    else:
        if class_or_type is ndarray:
            class_or_type = (ndarray, FakeArray)

    return _original_isinstance(object, class_or_type)

__builtin__.isinstance = isinstance
```

Comment: To be clear, I *don't* want it to work in numpy code, every external function (and most internal functions) are already covered by the class. I just want to fake `isinstance` and `issubclass`.

Comment: I guess it's not really possible to do. It's really weird that you can't actually override parent classes' `__new__` without also using `super()`.