# Registering a class as a subclass of a numpy array (without subclassing)

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing, registering

Without subclassing from numpy `ndarray`, I have a class that implements all `ndarray` methods. In spite of this, some numpy operations fail. It seems to me that, `isinstance(obj, ndarray)` is used inside numpy code. Is there a way to register (like in [abc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html)) my class as a subclass of a numpy ndarray (without subclassing)?

Comment: Why are you so against subclassing? That seems like the way to go here...  You are already overriding all of ndarrays methods anyways so it would maintain the same functionality just with ndarray as its parent class.

Comment: It seems that this might be very similar to this other question from the other day:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18284660/748858

Comment: @EEP -- Of course, if you really override *all* the parent class's methods, it seems that there is no longer a point to subclass ;-P

Comment: For what it's worth, with `abc`, I think you can easily add ndarray as a subclass of your class, but not the other way around (unless `ndarray` happens to have `ABCMeta` as a metaclass ...)

Comment: @EEP: I am wrapping another array type, and I would rather not copy the data into a numpy array as it is too big.

Comment: Does the other array type hold its data in a contiguous block of memory? Because you could wrap it in an `ndarray`, e.g. with `np.frombuffer`.

Comment: @mgilson: I think that is exactly the problem. `ndarray` does not seem to have `ABCMeta` as metaclass. I think it could be a nice addition.

Comment: @Jaime: Thanks for the tip, but is not contiguous.

Comment: Exactly what NumPy operations fail and what is the error they return? Something really crude like: `class Dummy(object):;    def __add__(self, x): return x+5;    def __radd__(self, x) return x-5;` works as expected: `Dummy() + np.arange(3)` outputs `array([5, 6, 7])` and `np.arange(3) + Dummy()` outputs `array([-5, -4, -3], dtype=object)`.

Comment: @Jaime: The problem happens mostly with Numpy functions that call `asarray` or `asanyarray`. They create a copy as they fail to see that my class behaves like an ndarray.

Comment: @Hernan, why create a copy? They should only create a view if you have exposed any of: the python buffer API, `__array_struct__`, `__array_interface__` or `__array__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array interface: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html. This allows to use numpy ufuncs with your class.

You can have a dynamic **array_interface** if you use it as a property.